# How to use kgdb over ethernet (kgdboe)?

Tags: linux

i am using ubuntu 12.04 and kernel version is 3.12.6, i want to learn how to use kgdb to debug kernel. I didn't get much info. regarding **kgdboe** (kgdb over ethernet). I have compiled kernel and enabled kgdb in **menuconfig**, i have created kernel image using **make bzImage** on development machine and copied same on target machine, now problem is how to connect both target and development machine. i m not getting parameter set for **kgbdoe**. Plz help if anybody know how to use kgdb over ethernet

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have you read this:
https://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/people/jwessel/kgdb/ch03s04.html 
?

You have to run debugged kernel with special options - like for example:

```
kgdbwait kgdbcon kgdboe=@192.168.248.76/,@192.168.242.24/00:11:22:33:44:55
```

and on debugging side you run following commands:

```
gdb
file vmlinux
target remote udp:192.168.248.76:6443
```

it has worked for me.

Comment: i tried the above command, it is showing kgdbwait : command not found

Comment: I meant you have to start kernel adding those options to kernel command line- for example to grub.conf or uboot or redboot - depending what you are using.

Comment: ok i added
kgdbwait kgdbcon kgdboe=@dev_machine_ip/,@target_machine_ip/mac_of_target in /etc/default/grub file, rebooted the sys and ran gdb on the other machine. after giving target remote udp:ip:port it is showing connection refused.

Comment: It seems there is problem with network, check if there is connection between both systems, or maybe there is some misprint in i.e. ip address? Debugged systems after very early boot should wait for gdb connection on default port 6443.

Comment: connection is proper... target machine is pinging from development machine... i dont know why it is not waiting for connection..i edited grub file on development machine and rebooted it then on testing machine i started gdb.

Comment: grub should be reconfigured on debugged machine not on the development one. Gdb should be run on development machine.

Comment: Hi all, sorry for digging this thread up, but I'm also trying to use kgdboe to connect the target and host machine. Is it possible to do it linking the two machines directly with an ethernet cable, or they must be both on the same LAN and not directly connected? In the case the direct connection is possible, which target/host IPs should then I specify on the kgdboe option? Many thanks for reading!

Comment: I think that both machines can be connected directly. How to configure kgdboe is described here: https://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/people/jwessel/kgdb/ch03s04.html

Comment: not working for me as well. added the following line in  **/etc/default/grub** file :
    GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash kgdbwait kgdbcon kgdboe=@192.168.4.1/,@192.168.4.2/08:00:27:d7:3d:16"
where Ist ip is development machine, and IInd ip is target (i hope this is the order). updated the grub file and reboot, but kernel is not waiting at kgdbwait.

Comment: Worth noting, no need to boot with any special options, for me `insmod` of the kgdboe.ko along with passing it a port number worked. Afterwards connecting over the network with gdb worked *(though machine hanged for some reason after gdb got connected, and gdb shows no stack and says "program not being run". Idk what happened)*.

Answer (score 4):

You can get the kgdboe source from [here](http://visualkernel.com/kgdboe/), build it and load it into your kernel:

```
make -C /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/build M=$(pwd)
sudo insmod kgdboe.ko
```

Then type 'dmesg' to see the load log and get instructions on connecting from gdb.

Comment: To make `insmod` work I had to pass it the adapter to use, like this: `insmod kgdboe.ko device_name=enp0s25 udp_port=3333`