# I want to debug vmlinux on arm board using gdb through minicom. What all thing I need to do?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, arm, gdb, gdbserver

I have a arm board, I connect it with my linux (host) system via a wire. I insert sd card with vmlinux.uimg in the arm processor and use minicom on host system. Now I want to debug vmlinux on arm board using gdb. What all thing I need to do? I tried using gdbserver on minicom and gdb on host. But I don't know how exactly it work... Where should I copy vmlinux and how should I debug...

Answer (score 2):

Complete answers depend on your Linux version, development and target setup.  Here are some research links,

- [gdb kernel debugging](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/Documentation/dev-tools/gdb-kernel-debugging.rst)
- [kgdb](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/Documentation/dev-tools/kgdb.rst), [kgdb docbook](https://www.kernel.org/doc/htmldocs/kgdb/Introduction.html) or [formatted docbook](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/v4.13/dev-tools/kgdb.html)

You need to configure your kernel with **KGDB** support and you can use the console as a link to control **KGDB** from your development machine.  You need copies of the vmlinux object files on the development machine; easy if it is also the build machine.  There are script for GDB to access handy information in the kernel.  This is the info in the GDB kernel debugging link.

You do not use `gdbserver`; this is for user space linux processes.  The tool for debugging the kernel is **kgdb** and this requires code to be put into the kernel.  Normally the program `gdbserver` is using kernel facilities to control a process.  This won't work for the kernel itself.

It is possible that not all serial ports will support kgdb.  Some versions of Linux allowed [kgdb over the network](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21300420/how-to-use-kgdb-over-ethernetkgdboe).  However, it is not present in as many kernels as the serial port.  You can activate kgdb over serial with a kernel parameter `kdbgoc`, *sysfs* or magic sysreq.  Some devices (and Linux versions) may have support for JTAG type kgdb.