# How to debug Linux Kernel on a remote machine?

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, gdb, kgdb

How to debug a custom Linux Kernel on a remote machine?

I have a remote machine with a custom-built Linux Kernel originally from 5.6.8. The system under the kernel is running into problems which I want to fix. The kgdb-related options are

```
CONFIG_KGDB=y
CONFIG_KGDB_SERIAL_CONSOLE=y
# CONFIG_KGDB_TESTS is not set
CONFIG_KGDB_LOW_LEVEL_TRAP=y
CONFIG_KGDB_KDB=y
```

The `kgdboc` module is compiled builtin. The [documentation of kgdb](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/v5.6/dev-tools/kgdb.html) describes how to use terminal with a serial port. Here is how it is configured on the remote machine:

```
root@remote-pc:# cat /sys/module/kgdboc/parameters/kgdboc
ttyS0,115200
```

Using `ssh` I issued

```
root@remote-pc:~# echo g > /proc/sysrq-trigger
```

And after running `gdb vminux` what port should I use to connect to the remote Kernel?

```
(gdb) target remote remote-pc:__what_port?__
```

Comment: What do you mean, what port? You started the debugger on a serial console, so whatever you connected the other side of the serial port to. Did you connect the serial ports, or did you mean to use `kgdboe`?

Comment: @Cheatah Actually have not heard about `kgdboe` (only `kgdboc` is not documented under the doc page I linked)

Comment: @Cheatah Is it even possible to connect to a serial port remotely?

Comment: That depends on what you define as "remotely". If you have an embedded system, connect the serial port to another system, I consider that to be remote, in a way. On a virtualised system you could tunnel it over SSH or something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot connect to a *literally* remote machine through a serial port. What you want to use is KGDB Over Ethernet (`kdgboe`). See [How to use kgdb over ethernet (kgdboe)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21300420/how-to-use-kgdb-over-ethernetkgdboe)

Comment: Just found this: https://github.com/b1f6c1c4/ttyssh. It seems it is possible to tunnel it.

Comment: @SomeName well, I suppose you can tunnel it through SSH as you can do for basically anything. Didn't think about that possibility, not sure how easy it is though. Hope it works!